# Failed to start Nodemanger in hadoop on windows

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I configured Hadoop in windows 7 from tutorial (http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/), setting up a Single Node Cluster. When I run `start-all.cmd` only `ResourceManager` is getting started. Unable to start `namenode`, `datanode` and `nodemanager`.

I get below error:

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method).
```

Has anyone faced or fixed such issue?

Answer (score 0):

After many days of search on google finally i realized its better to work on Linux (might be done through VM on windows). Because the libraries that are available on internet might not work on your system, otherwise you will have to generate your own system specific libraries form binaries available on internet to run Hadoop on your windows.